# What do you think about oforms Orchard module?

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I recently try oforms module on orchard and I confess that I was expecting more.

- My form not validating on IE8.
- No ServerSide validation
- No complex validation using Regex
- Impossible to fill in dropdownlist options from a DB or an xml file
- Impossible to set up workflows except e-mails

did I miss something that could change my opinion and make me buy this product ??

Comment: does anybody use this product?

Comment: my mistake, I was confused by http://extendorchard.co.uk/license-oforms "for a small fee you can remove the link from the Orchard oForms admin page"

Answer (score 1):

it does what it says it does. So it looks like a good module. Would be nice to have server side validation.

It works for me in IE8.